# Can I use PHP anonymous function as an argument, without assigning the function to a variable?

Tags: php, anonymous-function, php-5.6, php-7.1

Does PHP allow the use of an anonymous function as one of the arguments during concatenation?

If so, what is the proper syntax?

For example, here's an example of what I want to get to work:

```
$final_text = $some_initial_string . function ($array_of_strings)
{
    $out = '';
    foreach ($array_of_strings as $this_particular_string)
    {
        $out .= $this_particular_string;
    }
    return $out;
};
```

Comment: And what do you expect to get? A string? A function? A *"stringfunction"*?

Comment: Tried implode()?

Comment: [What you're trying to achieve with this question absolutely and completely can not be done in PHP.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

Comment: I am not entirely sure what you are trying to achieve ... and do you have to use anonymous function for that?

Comment: An explanation for the down votes would have been great . . .

Anyway, I expected a string to be returned from the anonymous function that would then just be concatenated onto the others.

Comment: Downvote was probably because you're not asking about the problem but perceived solution, without trying this code to assert whether it works. This is known as XY problem. Also, other comments highlighted that you're after `implode` function.

Comment: I didn't downvote but I am thinking that it was not clear what you were asking from the get go and the code had bugs.

Comment: as of php7  you can do this: `'text ' . (function () {return '';})()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: the below is expected to work for PHP Version 7.x but does not work on PHP Version 5.6 (For 5.6, first assign the anonymous function to a variable)

```
/*
 * Strings before & after
 */
$table_heading_text = "HEADING";
$table_bottom_text = "BOTTOM";

/*
 * Use the function this way
 */
echo $table_heading_text . (function (array $array_of_strings)
{
    $out = '';
    foreach ($array_of_strings as $this_particular_string)
    {
        $out .= $this_particular_string;
    }
    return $out;
})(array(
    "hi",
    "mom"
)) . $table_bottom_text;
```

In short ...

1. function must return some value that can be converted to text
2. function definition must be enclosed in parenthesis `( ... )`
3. Don't forget to have calling arguments after the function definition

Examples:

```
echo "BEFORE" . (function ($x){return $x;})(" - MIDDLE - ") . "AFTER";
echo "BEFORE" . (function (){return " - MIDDLE - ";})() . "AFTER";
```

Also, using [implode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) may be better for this particular task.

Comment: Not quite.  Something like
`$table_string = $table_heading_text
      . function ($table_row_data) {
         $out = '';
            foreach($table_row_data as $row_data) {
               $out .= '<tr><td>'. $row_data->field .'</td><tr>';
            }
         return $out;
       }
      . $table_bottom_text;`

Comment: I'm not sure how `table_string` or string assignment fits into your existing question...

Comment: This totally misses the point of the question though : *"Does PHP allow an anonymous function during concatenating?"* ... to which the simple answer is no.

Comment: @Loren, how about now?

Comment: Thanks for the effort, Dennis, but I know I can use a function that way.  I simply was asking about using an anonymous function.

I'd give you at least a +1, but unfortunately the down votes put my reputation to below being able to do that :-(

Comment: well, `$final_text(array("hi", "mom"))` is a call to anonymous function. You just put that function into a variable name, but the function still has no name.  You can use parenthesis to avoid assigning the function to a variable.  See my answer now .... is that closer to what you were looking for?

Comment: No, I get `Catchable fatal error: Object of class Closure could not be converted to string`

Comment: Try this line `echo "BEFORE" . (function ($x){return $x;})(" - MIDDLE - ") . "AFTER";` does it work for you?  Make sure you have parenthesis with calling arguments after the function

Comment: I get `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ',' or ';' `.

That was a direct copy of `echo "BEFORE" . (function ($x){return $x;})(" - MIDDLE - ") . "AFTER";`

I also get the same error when copying everything from your answer concerning the table text.

Comment: What version of PHP are you using?  I seem to be able to run it on PHP 7.1.6

Comment: I'm using PHP version 5.6.

Comment: I would probably blame the errors on the PHP version.  If you can, use PHP Version 7.x.  I think it should work there.

Comment: Alright, I'll accept that as the answer.   @Deadooshka stated as much as well in the comments under my original question.  Looks like I'll have to contact my host to upgrade :-)

Thanks for the persistence!

Comment: Sure thing.  Some hosts usually have several versions already installed, and there are ways to indicate which version you want to use via some configuration parameter.

Comment: @Dennis -- just want to follow up and let you know that I'm now running 7.0 and everything works like a charm.  Thanks again for you persistence!

Comment: Hey great! I'm glad it helped, thanks for the update!